# How to check that the value of an array object's property contains only letters?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do make a function to check if the `name` property-value contains only alphabetical characters? I've searched and haven't found a way, can anyone help or give the right post for this case?

```
arr1 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'test'},
  {id: 2, name: 'test123'},
]

arr2 = [
  {id: 1, name: 'test'},
  {id: 2, name: 'test'},
]
```

The result I want is that `arr1` returns `false` and `arr2` returns `true`. I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
var allNameLatter = arr1.some(e => {
   return /^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/.test(e.name);
})
```

Comment: Look at documentation for the [`Array.prototype.some()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), and then - probably - use [`Array.prototype.every()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) instead. Also, when asking a question phrases such as "it did not work" are not useful, instead you have to tell us *what* didn't work? In what way? How did it break, what did it do instead of working?

Comment: thank you sir David for fixing my question and helped me to solve this case.